# I need present list of fact like string in CLIPS

Tags: clips

I need your help. I have a facts like

```
(fact (name1)(value1))
(fact (name2)(value2))
(fact (name3)(value3))
```

And I wanna ask the question:

```
(printout t "Which of the fact do you like? " value1 value2 value3)
```

How can I present facts like string?

Answer (score 0):

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate info
   (slot name)
   (slot value))
CLIPS> 
(deffacts initial
   (info (name n1) (value v1))
   (info (name n2) (value v2))
   (info (name n3) (value v3)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule query
   =>
   (bind ?values (create$))
   (do-for-all-facts ((?f info)) TRUE
      (bind ?values (create$ ?values ?f:value)))
   (printout t "Which of the facts do you like? " ?values crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Which of the facts do you like? (v1 v2 v3)
CLIPS>
```